# what is inline query? can anyone define with a concise and clear Example?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-server-2008, development-environment

The idea i have is that inline query is ->  query within query .. is that right?

and this exists in sql server DB or DB query like in stored procedures we write or may relate to c# code and how we write it in c#??
These are two things i am not clear about..!

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query within a query is a subquery.

An inline query is sql code hardcoded inside some other platform such as C# e.g.

string mysql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"

Answer (score 3):

An inline query is a type of sub-query present in FROM clause of a SQL as a data source.

Below is the type of sub-query:

> If it present in the **SELECT** list, it is called “**sub-select**”.
>
> If it present in the **FROM** clause, it is called “**inline-query**”
>   or “**inline-view**”.
>
> If it present in **WHERE** clause, it may be simple sub-query or
>   “**co-related sub-query**”.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

An inline query to me is when I **DO** use SQL in code, and **DO NOT** choose (.e.g) an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) or other technology to avoid SQL.

So:

var sql = "SELECT Name FROM Customer WHERE ID = 1";

instead of:

var customer = mapper.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);

There are a lot of definitions out there, so it would help to provide some context.

There are some mappers (Dapper) that let you almost write SQL (and so do many ORMs), so IT TRICKY :)

It could refer to **NOT** using Stored Procedures and many other ways of not having SQL in your codebase. This could be quite literally any other way, so make a REST call, GraphQL, OPath, ....